# jquery show and hide work but toggle doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about jQuery. When I am using hide/show then it's working but when i try use toggle() instead then it's doesn't work. What's the problem?

Thanks in advance.
This is my code:

```
/* Dropdown menu - Start */
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.enmenu').on('click', function(){
        $('.ensettings').toggle();
        return false;
    });

    $('html, body').on('click',function(){
        $('.ensettings').hide();
    });

    $(".ensettings").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
/* Dropdown menu - End */
```

Comment: running your code and .toggle() works just fine.

Comment: Did you post the wrong code? The current doesn't use `.toggle()`

Comment: Yes i edited the code. Check it.

Comment: Problem is likely that the event bubbles to body and gets hidden by event handler there. Stop the propagation on the `$('.enmenu').on('click'` and see if it works then

Comment: I don't know exactly what is your definition of "doesn't work", because it seems to work pretty well: https://jsfiddle.net/pqn1a34L/